# Video as splash

Tags: android, android-layout, android-video-player

I want to play a video file from raw folder as splash.But it is not working.Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem.

This is my code

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener{

    private MediaController mc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.sea);
        //mc = new MediaController(this);
        //vd.setMediaController(mc);
        vd.requestFocus();
        vd.setVideoURI(uri);
        vd.start();
        // vd.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

And my layout is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center">

  <VideoView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/VideoView">
  </VideoView>

< /LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is problem.. is it playing the video

Comment: no.It displays error as Sorry,this video cannot be displayed

Comment: 07-30 15:48:57.460: I/VideoView(18540):     Setting size: 320x480

07-30 15:48:57.476: E/MediaPlayer(18540): error (1, -22)

07-30 15:48:57.476: E/MediaPlayer(18540): Error (1,-22)

07-30 15:48:57.484: D/VideoView(18540): Error: 1,-22
0

Comment: @user2159490 Are testing this on `emulator`  or `real device` ? and what is the type of video ? (3gp, mp4, etc..)

Comment: Tested on real device.And the type of file is mp4 with 5sec duration and 4.63mb size

Comment: if It displays error as Sorry,this video cannot be displayed ..it means your video is not proper..to test it just try any video.there is no mistakes in ur code

Comment: convert your video to `3gp` format and give a try.

Comment: tried 3gp format.but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

    private String mSplashVideoPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        mSplashVideoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + PATH;

        copyVideoFile();

        final VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(mSplashVideoPath);
        mVideoView.start();

        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void copyVideoFile() {
        final File videoPath = new File(mSplashVideoPath);

        if (!videoPath.exists()) {
            videoPath.mkdirs();
        }

        final File videoFile = new File(mSplashVideoPath);

        if (!videoFile.exists()) {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open(ASSETS_SPLASH_VIDEO);
                out = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mSplashVideoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + PATH;
what is PATH? explain a bit...